# How To Reverse A Nested Python List

Tags: python

Given the following nested list,

`myList=([1,[2,3],[[4,5,[6],7],8,9]])`

I want to reverse it to be converted into:

`myList= [[[4, 5, [6], 7], 8, 9], [2, 3], 1]`

How do I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I really cannot see where is the reversing if the result is 4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,1? Do you want to reverse only the first two elements of the list and the put them at the end?

Comment: @edalorzo that too wont do. i was asked to make this ([1,[2,3],[[4,5,[6],7],8,9]]) look like this [[[4, 5, [6], 7], 8, 9], [2, 3], 1] dont know where to start :(

Comment: @arxanas Thanks that worked but i need to write a user defined function

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is quite easy, you can reverse this :

**myList=([1,[2,3],[[4,5,[6],7],8,9]])**

by

**myList = myList[::-1]**

That's it !

Answer (score 2):

You can define a recursive procedure that checks if an element is a list itself. If an  element is not a list it is appended to the result directly. If an element is a list the procedure does a recursive call with this list-element as an input etc. The final result is the reversed list:

```
def is_list(p): 
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(mylist):
    result = []
    for e in mylist:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            result.append(deep_reverse(e))
        else:
            result.append(e)
    result.reverse()
    return result
```

For example:
A list [1, [8, 9, [4, [5, 9]]]] becomes
[[[[9, 5], 4], 9, 8], 1]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with list slicing

```
In [60]: myList
Out[60]: [1, [2, 3], [[4, 5, [6], 7], 8, 9]]

In [61]: myList[::-1]
Out[61]: [[[4, 5, [6], 7], 8, 9], [2, 3], 1]
```

For more info, go to 
    https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Answer (score -2):

If this is really homework, it should be tagged as such, otherwise, the answer to "a user defined function to reverse a list" could be the function:

```
import copy
def rev(l):
    lc = copy.deepcopy(l)
    lc.reverse()
    return lc
```

This assumes you don't want to reverse the original list in place (and aren't being tasked to actually develop a function that's already provided by the runtime, which could quite possible be the case were you to have tagged this as homework... ;)