# reversing a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, reverse, nested-lists

Hello I am trying to convert nested lists in reverse order .

here is my code :

```
def reverse_(items):
     items =  items[::-1]
        new_l = []
        for item in items:
            if type(item) == list:
                item.reverse()
                new_l.append(item)
            else:
                new_l.append(item)
        return new_l
```

1. `print(reverse_reversed([1, [2, 3, 4, 'yeah'], 5] ))` returns : `[5, ['yeah', 4, 3, 2], 1]` which is correct
2. but `print(reverse_reversed([42, [99, [17, [33, ['boo!']]]]])` returns : `[[[17, [33, ['boo!']]], 99], 42]` which should be this :  `[[[[['boo!'], 33], 17], 99], 42]`

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685757/how-to-reverse-a-nested-python-list fixes you problem ?

Comment: It can be simply `return [reverse_(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in items[::-1]]`

Comment: You're doing the reverse operation only twice. So can work in cases of a list inside a list, But will fail for nested lists beyond that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Reverse A Nested Python List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685757/how-to-reverse-a-nested-python-list)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it fixes , can you please post it as answer so that I can accept :) thank you very much for your help guys yes I was checking those links but Juanpa solves my problem

Comment: @DarrylG Isn't that just about reversing the outermost list?

Comment: @superbrain--the linked program is recursive to work on nested lists and provides the requested output.

Comment: @DarrylG Hmm, I guess. You linked to a question, not an answer, but yes, there's one answer that doesn't solve that linked to question but solves this one.

Comment: @superbrain--yes, it is a link to a question (as is the usual practice). The idea is that it should be a link to a question with at least one good answer.  In this case, I was referring to the answer by martin in the link and think it's somewhat equivalent to the accepted answer here, with the difference being the accepted answer here uses a list comprehension while martin uses a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to reverse lists *recursively* not just once nested. That means you need to make a recursive function call, i.e. it needs to call itself.

```
def recursive_reversed(items):
    if isinstance(items, list):
        return [recursive_reversed(item) for item in reversed(items)]
    return items
```

Notes:

1. I used an `isinstance` check instead of `type(item) ==`. This is usually what you want, and it means subclasses of `list` will be reversed too (although they will be regular lists).
2. No extra copy is made: `reversed` iterates over the original list in reverse order.
3. Nothing is reversed in place: if you look at the contents of your original list after calling your implementation, you will see its sublists will have been reversed as well.
4. I used a list comprehension which is generally preferred over "create an empty list, loop over something else, appending something to that list each iteration".
5. My function calls itself as a form of divide and conquer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you do `items[::-1]`, which makes the list to end up like this
`[[99, [17, [33, ['boo!']]]], 42]` And as you can see in your list are only two items `[99, [17, [33, ['boo!']]]]` and `42`. So you new If there are more lists in a list you will have to check if you are iterating through there are no unreversed lists in your list. But you can't do this with a simple for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't actually need a reversed copy but only want to reverse the structure itself:

```
def reverse(items):
    if isinstance(items, list):
        items.reverse()
        for item in items:
            reverse(item)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [42, [99, [17, [33, ['boo!']]]]]
>>> reverse(a)
>>> a
[[[[['boo!'], 33], 17], 99], 42]
```

You could also end it with `return items` to get the result returned:

```
>>> reverse([42, [99, [17, [33, ['boo!']]]]])
[[[[['boo!'], 33], 17], 99], 42]
```

Though it's somewhat unusual to both modify and return, and some people won't like it.